# vertically align a text in a responsive div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for a vertical div

css

```
.container {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 60%;
height: 60%;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-radius: 25px;
```

}

html

```
<div class="container">
  random text 
    </p>
  random text
  random text 
    </p>
  random text
  random text 
    </p>
  random text
</div>
```

I am having trouble figuring out how in this div to put text also to be vertically aligned and be responsive ?

jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/h49xx972/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following - this works for me on codepen. I added a css id that centered the text (I assume both vertical and horizontal is your requirement)

CSS

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#text_container {
    position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

}
```

Updated HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="text_container">
  random text 
    </p>
  random text
</div>
</div>
```

my codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdKdax

thx

Comment: thanks - that worked. I guess I can also use a class with the same.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in another div without declared dimensions ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h49xx972/3/)):

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="text-container">
      random text 
        </p>
      random text
      random text 
        </p>
      random text
      random text 
        </p>
      random text
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.container, .text-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.text-container {
    text-align: center;
}
```